# Architecture to grab range

Tags: excel, vba

My code mostly works but it's taking a while to debug so I am beginning to think my architecture may be flawed XD **So how can I architect this better?**

I have groups of data separated by a blank row. You can tell each group apart by the ID in column C in addition to the blank row. For each ID, I have various numbers in column B that I need to capture. Sometimes those numbers only start with `5`, sometimes it starts with `7`. I need to capture the 5 and the 7 separately.

```
With projWS

    With .Range("C1:C6000")
        Set f = .Find(cc, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart) 
    End With

    If Not f Is Nothing Then 'first occurence found
        counter = 0 
        i = f.Row 

        Do 
            acct = .Cells(i, 2) 

            If (Len(projWS.Cells(i, 3)) < 1 Or Left(acct, 1) = "7") And done = False Then
                acctStart = f.Row 
                acctRows = i - acctStart 

                Set acctRng = .Range(.Cells(acctStart, 2), .Cells(i - 1, 5))
                Set amountRng = .Range(.Cells(acctStart, 7), .Cells(i - 1, 8))

                done = True 'set flag to show range has been filled
            End If

            counter = counter + 1 'increment counter
            i = i + 1 'move to next row

        Loop Until Len(.Cells(i, 3)) < 1 'keep looping until blank row
    End If

    If counter - 1 > acctRows Then 'how we determine if there's a "7"
        flag = True 'so we set flag to true
        Set depreRng = Range(.Cells(acctStart + acctRows, 2), .Cells(i - 1, 8))
        dep = depreRng.Value2 'store range into array
    End If

End With
```

---

After capture, I need to drop it into another worksheet. This worksheet already has a block of `7` built in. Hence this is the loop I am using to drop the range of `7`. There is no built in block for the `5`.

```
    For r = 112 To 120
        For k = 1 To UBound(dep())
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value2 = Trim(dep(k, 1)) Then
                Debug.Print .Cells(r, 1).Value2
                .Cells(r, 6) = dep(k, 6)
                .Cells(r, 7) = dep(k, 7)
                Exit For
            Else
                .Cells(r, 6) = 0
                .Cells(r, 7) = 0
            End If
        Next k
    Next r
```

I have debugged several errors already. The current one is that `depreRng` is breaking because my math is bad. Instead of debugging each error as I stumble onto it, **how can I architect this better**?

[image]

Comment: I architect it assuming there will always be `7`. The `if` statement is flawed....think I need an `else`...

Comment: Uhmmm, in fact the job is that you want to find the rows in col B with the numbers that start with 5 and the ones that start with 7 separately for save ones in a block and the others in another block of another worksheet, right? What are you going to copy in the second worksheet, the entire row, a part of it? And what about the same numbers in different blocks (different value in col C)? The numbers in col B are always 4 digits numbers or could be also something like 51 or 7834924?

Comment: I made it sound too complicated. I need to capture a range. And sometime I need to divide that range between those starting with 5 and those with 7. Edit: range meaning from column B to H. Edit2: the actual range doesn't matter. I am looking for architecture. Edit3: basically, how do I determine start of `5`, end of `5` and if applicable, start of `7` and end of `7`?

Comment: Is it possible that 5** and 7** are mixed? Does the numbers always have 4 digits or the number of digits may vary? Edit. How do you specify the range  inside which you whant to capture? With the "index" in column C?

Comment: It's always sequential. Number of digits is irrelevant. Not sure why anyone would capture a range/cell via number of characters.... Yes, column C is the first driver.

Comment: It's interesting know if the number have always 4 digits because you can determine if the number it's in the 5** range with the test _4999<number<6000_ and the same for the 7** range

Comment: Oh ok. I guess it makes more sense to me to just grab first character. I rewrote most of the `do loop` but still interested to see other ideas.

Comment: Oh so you want your `do loop` to test `>6999`? Can't tell if that's more or less math XD

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my approach it's different. First i use a filter for find the range of rows with the index you are looking for and then loop inside this filtered rows for find the 5xx and the 7xx range. The code:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rng_5xx_start, rng_5xx_stop, rng_7xx_start, rng_7xx_stop As Integer
rng_5xx_start = 0
rng_5xx_stop = 0
rng_7xx_start = 0
rng_7xx_stop = 0
Dim range_5xx, range_7xx As String

'filter for the index you are looking for
'specify the maximum range, the field is the "offset" from the column B (the firts of the range), so for filter for column C you need to put 2, criteria...is the critera :)
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$H$6000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="b"

'the filter returns only the rows with the specifyed index, now a for inside this rows for find the 5xx and the 7xx sub-ranges
For Each Row In ActiveSheet.Range("b1:b6000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If Cells(Row.Row, 2).Value > 4999 And Cells(Row.Row, 2).Value < 6000 Then
'or any test for understnd if i'm in the 5xx range, if you prefer use the strings use something like left(cells(row.row,2).value,1) = "5"
    If rng_5xx_start = 0 Then 'found the first row with a 5xx value
        rng_5xx_start = Row.Row 'set the start of the range to this row
    End If
    If rng_5xx_stop < Row.Row Then 'the row where i am is in the 5xx range and is grater than the current end i noticed
        rng_5xx_stop = Row.Row 'refresh the end of the range...at the end this will have the last number of row of the 5xx range
    End If
End If
If Cells(Row.Row, 2).Value > 6999 And Cells(Row.Row, 2).Value < 8000 Then
'same as above but for 7xx range
    If rng_7xx_start = 0 Then
        rng_7xx_start = Row.Row
    End If
    If rng_7xx_stop < Row.Row Then
        rng_7xx_stop = Row.Row
    End If
End If
Next

If rng_5xx_start = 0 Then
    'not found 5xx rows
    range_5xx = "" 'or False, or what you prefer...
Else
    range_5xx = "B" & rng_5xx_start & ":H" & rng_5xx_stop
End If

If rng_7xx_start = 0 Then
    'not found 7xx rows
    range_7xx = "" 'or False, or what you prefer...
Else
    range_7xx = "B" & rng_7xx_start & ":H" & rng_7xx_stop
End If

End Sub
```

That's how i would imagine a macro for your job ;)

**Edit 1:**
I forgot that this will leave the sheet with the filter on...use `activesheet.showalldata` for show all the rows and not only the filtered ones

**Edit 2:**
The tests

```
    If rng_5xx_stop < Row.Row Then
        rng_5xx_stop = Row.Row
    End If
```

and

```
    If rng_7xx_stop < Row.Row Then
        rng_7xx_stop = Row.Row
    End If
```

are not necessary, it's enough do `rng_5xx_stop = Row.Row` and `rng_7xx_stop = Row.Row` and save the two `IF` statements

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: I do, with a smaller range. Did you?

Comment: No, I don't think it works because `rng_5xx_stop < Row.Row` is going to be always true?

Comment: It's going to be always true inside the range of the filtered rows (by index) and if the number starts with "5" (or "7" in the other if).  Try the code, it works.

Comment: If it's always true, how can it determine which row to stop? I don't get the logic but if you say it works, I trust you.

Comment: This test don't determine the row to stop at, all the rows with the specifiyed index are looped, it determines the last row with a 5xx number.Let's consider your table with the "b" index: the filter returns the rows from 3 to 28, then we loop inside that range and will do the test: at row 3 rng_5xx_stop=0 and row it's 3, so rng_5xx_stop will be updated to 3, at row 4 same as above so rng_5xx_stop updated to 4, at row 5 same..and same until row 20...at row 21 the test 4999<number<6000 will be false until the end of the for each, so at the end in rng_5xx_stop we have the last row with 5xx number

Comment: In fact you are right, the test is not necessary, it's enough do `rng_5xx_stop = Row.Row` and `rng_7xx_stop = Row.Row` instead of the _IF_ statement

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping cells based on the first *number* of the cell values in column B (I am assuming that they can never be letters).  If that is the case, then you can create an array of 0 to 9 and store your ranges in there.  Then go through the `range.areas` in order to get the groupings you're looking for (as highlighted in your screenshot).

To do this, something like this is all you need.  I commented code to try to explain it more:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rColB As Range
    Dim BCell As Range
    Dim aRanges(0 To 9) As Range
    Dim SubGroup As Range
    Dim lRangeNum As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Change to your actual worksheet
    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'Change to your actual column range, this is based off the sample data
    Set rColB = wsData.Range("B1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    'Loop through the column range
    For Each BCell In rColB.Cells
        'Make sure the cell is populated and the starting character is numeric
        If Len(BCell.Value) > 0 And IsNumeric(Left(BCell.Value, 1)) Then
            'Get the starting digit
            lRangeNum = Val(Left(BCell.Value, 1))

            'Check if any ranges have been assigned to that array index location
            'If not, start a range at that array index
            'If so, combine the ranges with Union
            Select Case (aRanges(lRangeNum) Is Nothing)
                Case True:  Set aRanges(lRangeNum) = BCell
                Case Else:  Set aRanges(lRangeNum) = Union(aRanges(lRangeNum), BCell)
            End Select
        End If
    Next BCell

    'You can use any method you want to access the ranges, this just loops
    'through the array indices and displays the range areas of each
    For i = 0 To 9
        If Not aRanges(i) Is Nothing Then
            For Each SubGroup In aRanges(i).Areas
                'Do what you want with it here
                'This just selects the subgroup so you can see it found the groups properly
                SubGroup.Select
                MsgBox SubGroup.Address
            Next SubGroup
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting. I thought about storing data into an array but never the range itself! All the digits are treated the same except `7` so the array would just need to be 2 elements. You're too late though, I already rewrote my code XD

Answer (score 0):

I see you've allready rewritten your code, but I'd like to offer how I would do it and would like to know your thoughts about it. Would this be inefficient? I guess it could be because you have to read the first character in cells 4 times for every increment, but not shure if that is a big problem.

```
Dim start_row As Long
Dim end_row As Long

start_row = 1
end_row = 0
For i = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i - 1, 2) = "" Then
        start_row = i
    ElseIf Left(Cells(i - 1, 2), 1) <> Left(Cells(i, 2), 1) Then
        start_row = i
    End If

    If Cells(i + 1, 2) = "" Then
        end_row = i
    ElseIf Left(Cells(i + 1, 2), 1) <> Left(Cells(i, 2), 1) Then
        end_row = i
    End If

    If end_row <> 0 Then
        Call copy_range(start_row, end_row)
        end_row = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Another approach that lets you only read the character once could be

```
Dim start_row As Long
Dim end_row As Long
Dim char_above As String
Dim this_char As String

start_row = 1
end_row = 1
For i = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
        end_row = i - 1
        if i <>1 then Call copy_range(start_row, end_row,char_above)
        start_row = i + 1
    Else
        this_char = Left(Cells(i, 2), 1)
        If this_char <> char_above Then
            end_row = i - 1
            if i<> 1 then Call copy_range(start_row, end_row,char_above)
            start_row = i
        End If
        char_above = this_char
    End If
Next i
```

Let me know your thoughts.